# How to (un)mark an Oracle table read-only for the owner?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In my Oracle instance I have a table. It existed just fine for many years without problems, I run thousands of queries per day on it (through my software), mostly selects and inserts, with rare (once-a-week) updates.

Today, a week after the last update, I ran an update against it and it failed with an `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.

I am the owner of that table. I'm pretty sure that database didn't change much during the week, certainly not this table.

I can select from it just fine: `select * from table_x`, but updates and inserts fail: `insert into table_x select * from table_x where 1 = 0` with the weird `ORA-00942`.

Since I'm the owner, the usual visibility and privilege problems don't seem to apply, and googling, sadly, doesn't help. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, so any suggestions are very welcome.

How did I make an Oracle table read-only (or invisible) for myself (the owner)?

It's partitioned (not sure if that helps). It's about 50GB in size, half of that indexes (not sure if that helps either).

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the sample statement from PL/SQL Developer:
[image: Not much of a stack trace]

Comment: Can you show the entire error message stack? I can only imagine you have a trigger on the table, and it is *that* which is referencing a table which no longer exists. Look for a trigger, check its status, and what is in user_errors; but it might come down to visual inspection of the code to see which table it's trying to use. You can't make a table read-only to its owner, to go back to your question/title.

Comment: Although, a trigger would have to be doing dynamic SQL to get that error instead of just saying it's invalid and fails recompilation, I think. Interesting...

Comment: can you do a literal insert, insert into table_x values (1,2,3); - I'm guessing something is amiss with the select bit of your insert.

Comment: Do you have materialized view based on this table?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith no, I can't, added a screenshot

Comment: @JSapkota yes, I have several of them. Can that interfere with an update?

Comment: what does ALL_ or DBA_OBJECTS show where OBJECT_NAME = 'SALES_ARCHIVE' - wondering if there are any synonyms.

Comment: So I wonder this is because of materialized view log used for fast refreshing the view. Try `DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON <table_x>`

Comment: @thatjeffsmith It shows the table, its 40 partitions and a single public synonym that makes this table readily accessible for everyone

Comment: @JSapkota `DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON <table_x>` Helped, thanks a lot! Please, post this as an answer so I can accept it)

Comment: Might get a better response on dba stack exchange.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp response from fine folk around here around here is plenty good enough for me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once I ran the same situation, according to the trace file and little googling which referenced to Materialized View Log which is associated with master table.

Use the following command to drop the materialized view log

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON <table_x>
```